# The knife tool won't show the exact result that was done before pressing enter

Tags: knife-tool

[image]

So the first picture is right after I selected where I will cut, and the second picture is after pressing Enter/Space Bar which should apply my previous result to the world. But it is not what I asked blender for, and it tries to snap at vertices. In the tutorial video, it seems that I can cut edges without already existing vertices but it is not the case for me. How do I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congrats. You've encountered a weird limitation of the *Knife Tool.*
It acts up with too large near/far clipping range.

*Unexpected behavior with extreme clipping range (0,1mm-1000000mm)*
[image]

**Solution 01**
Adjust your clipping range
Lower the highest values, until the knife tool starts working correctly.

[image]

**Solution 02**
Use flat *orthographic view*.
Knife tool works fine even with extreme clipping values, when using *front/top/side orthographic view*.

[image]

**Note**
This is actually caused by 3D View limitations that all OpenGL/DirectX graphics applications have. It's not just a Blender thing.
You can read more about it in the [Blender Troubleshooting Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#troubleshooting-depth).