# Knife tool randomly snaps to weird places and creates weird geometry

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bezier-curves

So, I have been experiencing problems using the knife tool.

Normally, when I am using the knife tool it just creates a straight line between the two points I click. 
However, sometimes when I am about to confirm a cut,
[this appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGCNV.jpg). (it is trying to inform me that I have cut through an edge, but I did not go through that edge and it is far away from the path I am cutting).
When I click and confirm the second point, it cuts from the first point, through a weird path, usually to somewhere off my screen, and back to the second point.

This is an urgent project, help will be greatly appreciated :)

Software: Blender 2.81 2019-11-20 release

Hardware: MacBook Pro 13 inch, Late 2018, 2.3 GHz Quad-Cure Core i5, Iris Plus 655

Comment: Hello and welcome :). There is a [very similar question asked 9 hours ago](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/161886/78972). Would that help?