# Knife Tool creates redundant edges and faces

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, knife-tool

[image]

When I use the Knife tool, Blender 2.81 create edges and faces which I don't want.
How can I only create the edges and vertices which I draw with the knife tool?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). There was a [very similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161902/78972) just a few days ago. Let me know if it helps.